# Writing list of dictionaries to Influxdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-python, influxql

I have a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{"vins": "50EA1LGA5KA900001", "use": "abc", "owner": "Jack"}, {"vins": "50EA1LGA0KA900004", "use": "xyz", "owner": "Laura"}, {"vins": "50EA1LGA2KA900005", "use": "pqr", "owner": "Sam"}]
```

I want to write the above dictionary by creating a new influx measurement called **'vin_info'** as follows:
The output I expect is :

```
vins | use | owner
50EA1LGA5KA900001 | abc | Jack
50EA1LGA0KA900004 | xyz | Laura
50EA1LGA2KA900005 | pqr | Sam
```

The code I tried so far to write my data is:

```
 data =   [{"vins": "50EA1LGA5KA900001", "use": "abc", "owner": "Jack"}, {"vins": "50EA1LGA0KA900004", "use": "xyz", "owner": "Laura"}, {"vins": "50EA1LGA2KA900005", "use": "pqr", "owner": "Sam"}]
 db = 'abc'
 query = 'select * from vin_info'
    client = InfluxDBClient(host='*****', port=8086,database=db)
        print("Connection Established")
        client.write_points(data)
        result = client.query(query)
        print(result)
```

But getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

I am not sure how to insert the above data into influx measurement. Can someone please help me here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the query you're passing?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe I have updated my original post with the query. It is simple to select * from the table.

Answer (score -1):

```
query = 'select * from vin_info'
```

You are calling the measurement `vin_info`, which doesn't appear in the data.

Try this:

```
influx_data = []

for x in data:
    new_json = {}
    new_json.update("measurement", "vin_info")
    new_json.update("tags",x)

influx_data.append(new_json)
```

You should see all tags when you select the measurement.

Also, according to `influxDBClient` [doc](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb-client-python), query return a table.

So try this also:

```
tables = query_api.query(query)

for table in tables:
    print(table)
```